# How to combine multiple lists into one using first element of each list as key?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

I use Python 3.6.4. I have multiple lists inside a list, but with the same keys (first element of inner list) for certain elements:

```
[[1, 100],
 [1, 250],
 [2, 340],
 [2, 5200]]
```

Element `0` is the same for the first 2 inner lists. How can I combine those to one list by the same keys to get something like this:

```
[[1, 100, 250],
 [2, 340, 5200]]
```

In my case, max count of the same keys is always two.

Comment: I don't understand. You have two lists where the first element is the same and you want to merge them? So just `list1 += list2[1:]`?

Comment: Okay, my bad. I want to merge two list by first (`[0]`) element to one list.

Comment: @miradulo, since an answer has been accepted, I've taken the liberty to improve the question for other users. Should make sense now.

Comment: Is the nested list sorted by the first elements, jpp?

Comment: Wasn't specified in the question, so I assume not, but OP should clarify.

Comment: Well, neither was a nested list but alright. In any case, `itertools.groupby` is made for this if the first elements are sorted. `[[k] + list(map(itemgetter(1), grp)) for k, grp in groupby(lst, key=itemgetter(0))]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to use `collections.defaultdict` to iterate a list of lists.

Then use a list comprehension to transform your dictionary.

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = [[1, 100],
       [1, 250],
       [2, 340],
       [2, 5200]]

d = defaultdict(list)

for i, j in lst:
    d[i].append(j)

res = [[k]+v for k, v in d.items()]
```

Result:

```
[[1, 100, 250],
 [2, 340, 5200]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
default_dict = {}
for val_list in data:
    key, value = val_list
    default_dict.setdefault(key, []).append(value)
print(*[[key, *value] for key, value in default_dict.items()], sep="\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Or something like this:

```
lst=[[1, 100], [1, 250], [2, 340], [2, 5200]]

d={}                                         
for l in lst:         
    if l[0] in d:              
        d[l[0]]=[d[l[0]], l[1]]
    else:           
        d[l[0]]=l[1]

out=[]                                       
for k,v in d.items(): 
    v.insert(0, k)
    out.append(v)
```

Result:

```
print(out)
[[1, 100, 250], [2, 340, 5200]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own logic with one loop :

```
data=[[1, 100],
 [1, 250],
 [2, 340],
 [2, 5200]]

combine={}
for i in data:
    if i[0] not in combine:
        combine[i[0]]=[i[1]]
    else:
        combine[i[0]].append(i[1])
print(list(map(lambda x:[x,*combine[x]],combine.keys())))
```

output:

```
[[1, 100, 250], [2, 340, 5200]]
```